# We two close friends of opposite gender are very dear to each other and left each other for the sake of Allah and promised to meet in jannah. Will we?

Tags: allah, jannah, day-of-judgement, sacrifice, friendship

I have seen everywhere but there is not clear answer anywhere. Everyone talks about love but not friends. Will this promise be fulfilled? And will we remember this promise hereafter?

Answer (score 0):

If Allah forgives both of you and allows both of you to enter jannah then you might meet. Allah knows best.